# Android SDK - Downloading of files very slow

Tags: android, http, download

I built/copied a download function which gets images and videos via an URL and downloads them to an Android device.

When downloading small images it's no problem. But when trying to get files with more than `2MB` (via WLAN!) it takes literally ages! About 5 minutes for an 25MB video and so on.

Any ideas what might go wrong?

Here's my code:

```
        /* Open a connection to that URL. */
        URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

        /*
         * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
         */
        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

        /*
         * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
         */
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                baf.append((byte) current);
        }

        /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
        fos.close();
```

Comment: Maybe something with buffer size ....use DownloadManager....best way to download

Comment: thanks, but could you provide some code or a link?

Comment: See below there is an example

Comment: I think you should increase the read buffer. 50byets are really poor

Comment: what would be an appropriate size?

Comment: better would be 2k, 4k:) (2048, 4096).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DownloadManager to download files

```
        private long enqueue;
private DownloadManager dm;

 BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();


            if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(
                        DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
                Query query = new Query();
                query.setFilterById(enqueue);
                Cursor c = dm.query(query);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                    if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c.getInt(columnIndex)) {

                        Log.e("Download completed","HERE DOWNLOAD COMPLETED");
                        try
                        {
                                                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                        }

                    }
}
            }
}};
```

To start this download use:

```
         dm = (DownloadManager)activityContext.getSystemService(activityContext.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Request request = new Request(Uri.parse("URL")).setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("DIRECTORY","FILENAME");
    enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: looks similar to this one ;) http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/