# Add auto retry to Android Download Manager

Tags: java, android, download, android-download-manager

Thanks to [Navdeep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14645424/1331671) I built a working `DownloadManager`. The thing is that I need the app to retry downloading failed download after a certain delay.

Similar to [this](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/) post I added successfully an if-clause to check when a download is failed:

```
if (DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED == c.getInt(columnIndex)) { ... }
```

The question is how I can restart the download. I guess the download is somewhere in the `Query` or `Cursor`?

**Edit:**

After fiddling around I'm trying to put a delay handler into this if-clause and call the download like I do it in the first place. Unfortunately I have problems accessing the `COLUMN` attributes:

```
c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
```

This one causes a `NullPointerException`... Any ideas why?

Comment: You can delay for some time and call the same method which starts the downloadManager

Comment: i have problems accessing the `COLUMN` variables to get the uri and save path of my failed download... i always get a `NullPointerException`

Comment: You can make the Uri Global ...Can you show some code and your logcat.

Comment: its basically the line i added to my question. is this the correct way to get the uri? when I leave out the `getString` I just get a "13"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a NullPointerException because the download has not been completed and so doesnt give a location to the downloaded file. You can call the method that downloads the file again if the download fails